# wrap method using function as parameter

Tags: jquery, html, css

What's wrong with this code? Depending of the condition I want to set a double brown border or a solid blue border, but it doesn't matter what condition I use: `if($(this).has("#tt"))` or `if(($(this).has("ssssssss")))` or whatever, it keeps always putting double brown border...

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".divvv").wrap(function () {
        if ($(this).has("#tt")) {
            return $("<div/>").css("border","double thick brown")
        }
        else {
            return  $("<div/>").css("border","solid blue")
        }
    })
})
```

Html:

```
<div id="firstdiv" class="divvv">
 <label class ="lab" id="tt" for="two">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two" />
    <label class ="lab" for="four">4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="four" />
</div>

 <div class="divvv" id="secdiv">
<button id="bu">Here</button><button id="bubu"> Button</button>
    <label id="second">This is the <span style="color:aqua">second</span> label</label>
    <label>This is the third label</label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : `.has()` returning an object and not true or false. You can use `.has().length` which returns 1 i.e true if it has matched object otherwise 0 i.e false. See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".divvv").wrap(function () {
        if ($(this).has("#tt").length) {
            return $("<div/>").css("border","double thick brown")
        }
        else {
            return  $("<div/>").css("border","solid blue")
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstdiv" class="divvv">
 <label class ="lab" id="tt" for="two">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two" />
    <label class ="lab" for="four">4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="four" />
</div>

<div class="divvv" id="secdiv">
    <button id="bu">Here</button><button id="bubu"> Button</button>
    <label id="second">This is the <span style="color:aqua">second</span> label</label>
    <label>This is the third label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".divvv").wrap(function () {
        if ($(this).has("#tt").length) {
            return $("<div/>").css("border","double thick brown")
        }
        else {
            return  $("<div/>").css("border","solid blue")
        }
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="firstdiv" class="divvv">
 <label class ="lab" id="tt" for="two">2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two" />
    <label class ="lab" for="four">4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="four" />
</div>

 <div class="divvv" id="secdiv">
<button id="bu">Here</button><button id="bubu"> Button</button>
    <label id="second">This is the <span style="color:aqua">second</span> label</label>
    <label>This is the third label</label>
        </div>
```

.has() return an object everytime whether  match is present of not, but .has().length return 0 for no match and return 1 for a match.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/po2cvbqr/)